# Firefox 4 - NPAPI plugin works with 3.6 now declared corrupt!

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpi

Can anyone help with packaging a simple NPAPI plugin so it is compatible with Firefox 4, we have a plugin that works fine in all previous versions of Firefox but when it is tried it on Firefox 4 Beta 5 (latest version as of the question) then the browser declares it is corrupt.

If I run Firefox with the -console parameter on the command line then it displays this error message

> *** WARN addons.xpi: Invalid XPI: [Exception... "Component returned
>   failure code: 0x80520006
>   (NS_ERROR_FILE_TARGET_DOES_NOT_EXIST)
>   [nsIZipReader.getInputStream]" 
>   nsresult: "0x80520006
>   (NS_ERROR_FILE_TARGET_DOES_NOT_EXIST)"
>   location: "JS frame ::
>   resource://gre/modules/XPIProvider.jsm
>   :: loadManifestFromZipReader :: line
>   550"  data: no]

So it looks like the packaging has changed again (it broke on Firefox 3.6) but I cannot find any sane answers on what should be contained in an XPIProvider.jsm for a simple NPAPI plugin (i.e. it is just a single object within the plugin, provides a simple javascript extension and displays some simple UI content in an in browser element).

Can anyone help? Even pointing me at some documentation would be good, I cannot find anything relevant to NPAPI (lots of XPCOM very little NPAPI info).

Comment: This isn't an answer, but it bears mentioning that the problem here is not specific to NPAPI, but to XPI installations

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [em:unpack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/install_manifests#unpack) to your install.rdf for XPIs containing NPAPI plugins or any other binary components (XPCOM components, DLLs and such)